# How to refer in CSS to the (value of the) content of an HTML element?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

In the `CSS` of my `HTML` `table` I would like to insert conditional formatting code for the `td-elements`. If the value of such an element's content is lower than 500, I want that value to be displayed in red. If not, it should be in black.

So if in my table there is e.g. the code `<td>439</td>`, that number should be displayed in red. If it's `<td>578</td>`, it should be in black.

This is the `CSS` code I think would work (using the `SCSS` extension):

```
td {
    @if xxxxx < 500 {
        color: red
    } else {
        color: black
    }
}
```

What should I put instead of `xxxxxx`? Or perhaps you know of an alternative coding solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Comment: No. The question is for formatting based purely on the value of the inner element, not that of an attribute.